# How to store, and execute a derrived Class Member Function in the Base Class

Tags: c++, boost, pointer-to-member, member-functions

So im trying to create a basic state machine system for some of my automated entities in my program.

The idea is, automated entities will simply call whatever current state, or behavior it is currently assigned to. Each state will be assigned to 1 function.

Im having incompatibility issues with my member function pointers. Its apparent it is not possible to simply call a "derived member function pointer", as if it were a "base member function pointer".

I believe I need to be able to store some kind of "generic class member function pointer". Ive been reading many other posts and they are talking about using the boost::bind and boost:function as an option. Though Im not quite sure how to use that within my code context:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Automated
{
public:

    typedef void (Automated::*behaviourFunc)();

    void SetBehaviour(behaviourFunc newBehavFunc)
    {
        currentFunction = newBehavFunc;
    }

private:

    behaviourFunc currentFunction;

protected:

    void executeCurrentBehaviour()
    {
        (this->*currentFunction)();
    }
};

class Animal : public Automated
{
public:

    void update()
    {
        executeCurrentBehaviour();
    }
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
    int fishCount;

    void CatchFish()
    { 
        fishCount++;
    }

    void eatFish()
    { 
        fishCount--;
    }
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
    int boneCount;

    void FindBone()
    {
        boneCount++;
    }

    void throwBone()
    {
        boneCount--;
    }

public:

    Dog()
    {
        SetBehaviour(FindBone); //Error: argument of type "void (Dog::*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "Automated::behaviourFunc"
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Dog jake;
    Cat nemo;

    nemo.SetBehaviour(Cat::CatchFish);  //Error function "Cat::CatchFish" is inaccessible

    jake.update();
    nemo.update();

    return 0;
}
```

Since my automated entities will have an unknown amount of states, and hence have an unknown amount of functions I cannot create generic virtual methods.

What is the best way to store, and execute a derrived Class Member Function the Base Class.

Or, what is a way to store a generic member class function, and call that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the problem is that derived functions are looking for derived type member variables and the base class doesn't have them. I suspect the strongly typed inheritance system in C++ may not be the ideal approach. What about having a single class type that contains properties (like in a `std::map<std::string,std::string>`) and accept Functors (function object) to process the properties?

Answer (score 0):

So yes boost::function and boost:: bind was pretty much exactly what I was looking for.

I can store a boost::function within Class "Automated".

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>

class Automated
{
    //ideally there should use a function to set the "currentFunction" but
    //for learning purposes just make it public
    public:

        //function returns void, and no paramters
        boost::function<void()> currentFunction;

        //etc
 }
```

And simply call boost::bind in the derived classes

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class Cat : public Animal
{
    int fishCount;

    void CatchFish()
    { 
        fishCount++;
    }

    void eatFish()
    { 
        fishCount--;
    }

    Cat()
    {
        //This bind specifies a void return and no paramters just like the 
        //the signature for the "currentFunction"
        currentFunction = boost::bind(&HF_BattleEnemyBat::CatchFish, this)

       //You can simply call "currentFunction" like this:
       currentFunction();
    }
};
```

I found the following links to be very helpful. Straight to the point, and in my opinion a lot more clear than the boost docs themselves:

http://www.radmangames.com/programming/how-to-use-boost-function

http://www.radmangames.com/programming/how-to-use-boost-bind

These links also go in detail on how to use functions with parameters and different returns types.